# Sass styling is not applying to deployed firebase app but does locally

Tags: css, firebase, sass, parceljs

This is my first time deploying firebase and everything seems to be working except for the stylesheets are not being applied. I'm using parcel, sass and vanilla js. I've tried moving the style.scss into the public folder and updating the file paths in the index.html, that doesn't work. As well trying to update the path to the straight css style sheet in the dist folder. I've been redeploying successfully (with no styling) trying different things but I can't figure out where I need to put the style.scss file for firebase to pick it up. Has anyone dealt with this with sass/parcel and firebase? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you converting SCSS to CSS? SCSS isn't natively supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving EVERYTHING into the public folder. Then adjusting the link tag to the parcel generated css sheet got it working. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/style.97fcb138.css" />`